# Color overlay over image on hover

Tags: html, css

I have this example:

https://jsfiddle.net/3q81h1es/

```css
.image1 {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: url("http://www.avocat.dac-proiect.ro/wp/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/images/images1440/b1.jpg");
  margin-left: auto;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.image1:hover {
  opacity: 0.3;
  filter: alpha(opacity=30);
}
```

```html
<div class="image1"></div>
```

I want to make a blue haze effect, like in the picture below:

[image]

Can you help me to solve this problem?

I tried to add `.wrap{background:blue;}` but not working unfortunately.

Comment: Link doesn't work and there is no image supplied.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3q81h1es/3/ if you don't have to support old browsers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing block opacity would also change its content, so you might also try changing alpha channel of the overlay using pseudo elements and `rgba()` background color

```css
.image1:hover:after {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.3);
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
.image1 {
    background: url("http://www.avocat.dac-proiect.ro/wp/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/images/images1440/b1.jpg") repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    display: inline-block;
    height: 300px;
    margin-left: auto;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image1"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a blue overlay. This overlay can be made with a pseudo element and displayed on hover:

```css
.image1 {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: url("http://www.avocat.dac-proiect.ro/wp/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/images/images1440/b1.jpg");
  margin-left: auto;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.image1:hover:after {
  content:'';
  display:block;
  height:100%;
  background:blue;
  opacity:0.3;
  filter: alpha(opacity=30);
}
```

```html
<div class="image1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a second additional background using a single color gradient on hover.

```css
.image1 {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: url("http://www.avocat.dac-proiect.ro/wp/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/images/images1440/b1.jpg");
  margin-left: auto;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.image1:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 128, 0.25), rgba(0, 0, 128, 0.25)), url("http://www.avocat.dac-proiect.ro/wp/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/images/images1440/b1.jpg");
}
```

```html
<div class="image1">


</div>
```

As an alternative,  positioned pseudo-element if the div will have content.

```css
.image1 {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: url("http://www.avocat.dac-proiect.ro/wp/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/images/images1440/b1.jpg");
  margin-left: auto;
  vertical-align: top;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.image1:hover:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 128, 0.5);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="image1">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde magni officia odit enim magnam eaque modi illo dolorum necessitatibus cumque dolore recusandae nisi eos. Libero!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [CSS Blend Modes](http://www.w3.org/TR/compositing-1/#blendingmultiply)

[Browser Support is quite good](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-backgroundblendmode) (except for IE)

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/0Lpeoepr/1/)

```css
.image1 {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: url("http://www.avocat.dac-proiect.ro/wp/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/images/images1440/b1.jpg");
  margin-left: auto;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.image1:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, .3);
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

```html
<div class="image1"></div>
```